# How to make my Chrome extension transparent

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome-extension

I am building up a Chrome extension and it will pop up a small window with results that gets from database. Is it possible to make the pop-up window transparent so that users can read the webpage content without blocking? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is no way to do that for `pageAction` and `browserAction` popups. You can solve your task by inserting an HTML element with custom opacity via [content-script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)